# Pass variable to button

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Im fetching an URL on server-side.

```
<script>
    function onSuccess(ID_FOLDER) {
    var div = document.getElementById('output');
    var FolderPathURL = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/"+ID_FOLDER+"";
    div.innerHTML = '"+FolderPathURL+"'
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getFolderIds();

</script>
```

The variable FolderPathURL is now in the function onSuccess. I need to apply it to a button in the HTML view as a href (link). So when the user clicks the button they go the the link provided in "+FolderPathURL+". It should to me be a simple task, but i've been stuck now for 6 hours straight... :)

```
  <button class="action">View Folder</button>
```

I have so far tried the following without success, this replaces the blue css button that i need:

```
div.innerHTML = "<form><button formaction='"+FolderPathURL+"'>View Folder</button></form>"
```

And then this in the HTML:

```
  <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to apply it to a button in the HTML view as a href (link). So when the user clicks the button they go the the link provided in "+FolderPathURL+".

Try this, By placing a anchor tag inside the button

```
div.innerHTML = "<button formaction='"+FolderPathURL+"'>
                  <a href='"+ FolderPathURL +"' class='anchorButton'>View Folder</a></button>";
```

use this CSS rule

```
.anchorButton{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 background-color: Blue;
}
```

Comment: That worked, but the colours of the button is now inverted. The first button is the one i need, the second is how it looks right now. http://imgur.com/a/MjABO

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
var FolderPathURL = "/this/that/this/that.html";


document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<form><button formaction='"+FolderPathURL+"'>View Folder</button></form>";
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

I think your problem was just with the way you were selecting your div!

You were using:

```
div.innerHTML = blahblah;
```

In your case I think you need to use this:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = blahblah;
```

Hope this helps!

Good luck with your project!

Comment: why isn't his `div.innerHTML = blahblah;`not valid??

Comment: I guess it is.. but then why have id="output"

Comment: `var div = document.getElementById('output');` so now div is equal to `document.getElementById('output')`